# include_path is not updated as specified in php.ini

Tags: include, php, include-path

I set up include_path in php.ini.

Then I call `phpinfo()`

And `include_path` differs from that I specified in `php.ini`.

What can cause this?

I modified the same php.ini as specified in "Loaded Configuration File" in `phpinfo()` call.
php is called via apache module, I restarted apache - this also does not help.

I use Windows Vista, Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) PHP/5.3.1

I calls `set_include_path("...")` in the beginning of my php file, but this is good for temporary workaround only.

Comment: I was having this problem with a WAMP installation. It turns out that `wamp\bin\php\phpX.X.X>php.ini`, which I was manually editing, does not seem to be the one Apache reads from and the one it uses is `wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin>php.ini` Drove me absolutely crazy until I clicked on WAMP and went to `PHP>PHP.ini` and edited it from there, but you can access it directly in the directory above.

Comment: I am encountering exactly the same issue, but with PHP version 5.3.13. I am also running on windows. It seems that PHP is totally ignoring the `include_path` setting in `php.ini`. I have confirmed that the correct ini file is being read by changing other settings and they all change correctly. But no matter what I put in include_path, the include path is always set to ".;C:\php\pear".

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that there's a .htaccess file somewhere that is getting in your way. You can override php.ini settings in .htaccess files. E.g, in your .htaccess:

```
php_value include_path <path>
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste your `include_path=` entry from your php.ini.   I know php.ini entries have to be on one line and you need to have your directories separated by colons, but otherwise theres no trick to it.

Comment: I run it windows platform. Colons are used to separate drive letter

Comment: Try changing other settings in php.ini and rechecking phpinfo().  Do those stay or change?    Perhaps your php.ini can't be read by apache/php_mod due to security issues.

Comment: when I change php.ini in other places it is reflected on phpinfo() output

Comment: More than one include_path= setting in php.ini?   Otherwise, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure that your include_path starts with ".:" .

Comment: yes, it starts with '.;' (semicolons instead of colons, because I use Windows)