# How to change include_path in php.ini file?

Tags: php

I tried in many ways, but I am failing to make changes.,

I want to change include_path like this:

```
include_path = "c:\path\to\my\folder\file"
```

but while trying to print the include path using `get_include_path()`
Its printing like this:

```
'.;C:\php\pear'
```

Can anyone help me out?
I tried set_include_path also but its not working for me.

Comment: *I tried set_include_path* Show us your attempts!

Comment: possible duplicate of [include\_path is not updated as specified in php.ini](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813030/include-path-is-not-updated-as-specified-in-php-ini)

Comment: I understood my problem set_include_path(path);

Comment: I need to give in 'path' like this

Comment: May i know What is the problem in changing php.ini file. I don't want to use set_include_path for every application, Thanks for your help. In that post I didnt get any help for editing in php.ini thats why i posted it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change your include path in your `php.ini` file just search for `include_path` And you should find something like this:

```
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path=".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR"
```

Now you can change it here and restart the server and it should work!

**Side Note:**

I would recommend you to make a save copy before you change stuff in your php.ini file

For more information about include_path string see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Comment: @Akilsree1 Did you restarted your server? Also make sure the right php.ini file is loaded. And what does `get_include_path();` return ?

Comment: @Akilsree1 That's weird, it should work. Are you sure you changed it in the right php.ini file? If yes I have no idea

Comment: I am using wamp server _include_path='.;C:\php\pear;C:\wamp\www\api\src'_  I restarted my server 5-8 times. Even its not coming its printing only  **'.;C:\php\pear;'**   Sorry for late reply

Comment: @Akilsree1 Are you sure that you are updating the right php.ini file? Also try this: `include_path=".;C:\wamp\www\api\src"`

Comment: @Akilsree1 Do `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` And search for: `Loaded Configuration File` to see if you are updating the right file

Comment: Thank you So much @Rizier123. It finally worked... Have a nice Day :D